# Creating custom pop up keyboard nothing happen when keys are press

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

What I want to happen is that when a textbox is clicked a pop up keyboard will show and whatever i type on the keyboard will be putt in the textbox, but nothing happen but when I use notepad, it works. How can I fix this?

Here is my main form code:

```
    private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.ShowDialog();
    }
```

And here is my code for pop up keyboard

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;
//this line of code fixed the issue
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDesktopWindow")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams param = base.CreateParams;
            param.ExStyle |= WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;


//This line of code fix the issues
param.Style = 0x40000000 | 0x4000000;
                param.Parent = GetDesktopWindow();

            return param;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("1");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("2");
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("3");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: There is an on-screen keyboard packages with windows already, any specific reason for rolling your own?

Comment: @Tyriar, i only need numbers

Comment: I finally have solution for this, i cant answer my own question so i will just put the answer in the question

Answer (score 0):

Use `form1.Show()` ... not `ShowDialog()`

Answer (score 0):

If you manually added the testbox make sure you hook into the MouseEventHandler like so:

this.textBox1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.textBox1_MouseClick);

when your form loads.

Comment: nothing happens i cant still put into the the textbox what I click in the pop up keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by just adding this line of code

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDesktopWindow")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
```

And

```
                param.Style = 0x40000000 | 0x4000000;
            param.Parent = GetDesktopWindow();
```